# How to shard system basis on a particular id?

Tags: java, architecture, scalability, partitioning

We have a system of 6 machines in each datacenter and we have three datacenters. We have our app server deployed in each machines in all the datacenters. We also have caching layer in each app server we have deployed across all three datacenters.

Now what we need to do is :

- We need to shard our system basis on "customer id" which is a long datatype. What it means is - each machine in each datacenter should be responsible for particular "customer id's".
- In each datacenter we will hold two copies of each "customer id" data to avoid SPOF. Let's say if we are trying to get data for 1234 customer id, so first it will go to primary machine which has data for 1234 customer id but let's say if this primary machine is down, then it will go to secondary machine in the same datacenter to get the data for same customer id.

As of now our system is design like this:

We have 1780 memory mapped file and each file holds particular set of `customer id's` data only. And each machine is responsible for particular memory mapped file's and basis on this we are sharding the system. In general each machine is responsible for around 150 primary files and 150 secondary files so basis on this each machine knows what customer id data I am serving and our client knows which machine to call for a particular customer id.

My question is here we are using file as the concept to shard the "customer id" across all three datacenters. I am not sure how this will scale. I was looking at Cassandra architecture and how they are doing it internally, they are using `"vnodes"` and token ranges to partition the data.

**Question:-**

Is there any simplified approach which we can adapt to shard the customer id across each machine in all three datacenters instead of using this predefined 1780 files concept? This system is working fine so far but the problem is we are thinking to use Kafka and I believe Kafka performance will degrade if we have 1780 partitions. So I was trying to see how do people solve these kind of problem in general when we need to shard customer id across all machines in the datacenter.

NOTE: We cannot have each machine hold data for all the customer's since we have lot of data that we cannot store in memory in single machine so we are sharding across all our datacenters.

Comment: I'm coming at this from a very low-level standpoint, as my only experience with these kinds of topics is limited to implementing scalable servers for realtime purposes with very low-level C code. But it does sound to me like storing each customer record in a separate file could get a bit bottlenecky, plus perhaps actually more of a burden to maintain with issues like disk fragmentation to worry about. A common approach to avoiding this at the low-level is to just put all that data into a single, big binary file...

Comment: ... it can store a header, for example, containing the number of customers followed by customer IDs and absolute file offsets to seek to in order to get that data (provided it's merely an archive and not a search structure). You can store just that header into memory to be able to quickly get to the right position in the file given a customer ID. With that you should get considerably better performance than a lot of files with reduced seek overhead in addition to having a single file you can work with to backup all customers for that machine, e.g.

Comment: @lke The structure you have mentioned is exactly what you have in for each file. It's just that we have several files like that so that we can shard our system basis on that.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any simplified approach which we can adapt to shard the
>   customer id across each machine in all three datacenters instead of
>   using this predefined 1780 files concept?

Well, may be that will sound too easy, but I could propose the following.

You have a total of `T` machines to serve your customer database. You number your machines `0...T-1`. Now you put all information belonging to the customer with ID = N to machine #`N mod T` and #`(N-1) mod T`. This is the simpliest sharding key I could imagine, but it could be more complex if you need.